# Text classification CNN nan loss

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, text-classification

I'm attempting to train a neural network for text classification (sarcasm detection on reddit comments). I have the comment itself, its parent comment, and the subreddit in which these comments were made.

I engineer features such as the positivity, negativity, and neutrality of the comment, the same for the parent comment, and engineer 2 more numerical features based on the subreddit. This is a total of 8 engineered features.

The neural network I use is structured as such: I run a bunch of filters over my (word-embedding translated) comment, a bunch of filters over my parent comment (word-embedding translated), using a 1D CNN. I subsequently do some pooling and feed the outputs to a fully connected layer.

This works fine.

However, I wish to add in those 8 engineered features to my inputs to the fully connected layer. But when I do so, the loss decreases (rather quickly), and suddenly I see the loss turn to nan and accuracy decrease.

Below is the code within my function to produce the model: -

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                        embedding_dim,
                        weights=[embeddings],
                        input_length=max_sequence_length,
                        trainable=False)

parent_embedding_layer = Embedding(parent_num_words,
                        embedding_dim,
                        weights=[parent_embeddings],
                        input_length=max_sequence_length,
                        trainable=False)

sequence_input = Input(shape=(2, 205))
// some tensor manipulation

comment_sequence_input:= length 200 tensor of words in comment 
parent_sequence_input:= length 200 tensor of words in comment 

non_text_comment_input:= length 5 tensor with 5 engineered features
non_text_parent_input:= length 5 tensor with 5 engineered features

embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(comment_sequence_input)
parent_embedded_sequences = parent_embedding_layer(parent_sequence_input)

convs = []

// Convolutions

for filter_size in filter_sizes:
    l_conv = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=filter_size, 
                    activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
    l_pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(l_conv)
    convs.append(l_pool)
    
for filter_size in parent_filter_sizes:
    parent_l_conv = Conv1D(filters=parent_filters, kernel_size=filter_size, 
                           activation='relu')(parent_embedded_sequences)
    parent_l_pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(parent_l_conv)
    convs.append(parent_l_pool)  


// End of convolutions

//Inclusion of engineered features    
convs.append(non_text_comment_input)
convs.append(non_text_parent_input)

l_merge = concatenate(convs, axis=1)
// end of section


x = Dropout(0.30)(l_merge)

// Start of fully connected layer

x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
preds = Dense(labels_index, activation='sigmoid')(x)
adam_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.000001)
model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam_optimizer,
              metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
return model
```

The input provided is a (batch_dim, 2, 205) size tensor. 200 for the number of words in each entry, and 5 for the 3 sentiment engineered features and 2 subreddit engineered features. The 2 dimensions are for comment and parent comment.

Things I have tried:

1. Lowering the learning rate
2. Adding dropout
3. Normalising inputs
4. Normalising inputs and scaling them down by a factor of 100
5. Different optimizers (RMSprop, Nadam, etc)
6. Adding regularization (bias reg, kernel reg, activity reg) of various levels to my layers.

I tried testing this by setting all my engineered feature values to 0, and the network trains perfectly fine. Not sure what I should do here.

Comment: Can you post all your code?

Comment: @AloneTogether you can find it here https://www.kaggle.com/ramapriyan/share-cnn

Comment: https://github.com/ramapriyan912001/Sarcasm-Detection

Not sure why that was the case, you can check the repo here

Comment: Where is your dataset in your notebook?